# transmute called with types of different sizes

Tags: rust

I'm trying to build a Rust project with `cargo build` but I get this error:

```
error[E0512]: transmute called with types of different sizes
   |
90 |     ::std::mem::transmute(tenv)
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: source type: i32 (32 bits)
   = note: target type: *mut traction::Environment<JNIPlatform<'a>, std::string::String> (64 bits)
```

The code on which this breaks is this:

```
let tenv = env.get_field_unsafe(obj, JFieldID::from(field), jni::signature::JavaType::Primitive(jni::signature::Primitive::Int)).unwrap_alog().i().unwrap();
::std::mem::transmute(tenv)
```

I have no knowledge of Rust so I can only guess what this does.

Since this is a type conversion issue I'm assuming this has something to do with my operating system. Other people who cloned the same repository didn't have any issue like this (both on macOS and Windows). I have macOS Sierra 10.12.6.

Another question: how does `transmute` know what type to convert the variable that's given to it? `::std::mem::transmute(tenv)` takes only one argument, so how does it know both the source type and the destination type?

Answer (score 1):

The target type is a pointer, so it's architecture specific: 32 bits on a 32-bit platform, 64 bits on a 64-bit platform. `usize` and `isize` can be used in for this case.

If it's not your code, you should open an issue on the original repository.

You could try to build a 32-bit binary, using `rustup default stable-i686`

> how does `transmute` know what type to convert the variable that's given to it? `::std::mem::transmute(tenv)` takes only one argument, so how does it know both the source type and the destination type?

Rust infers the source and target type from the context, in the same way `Iterator::collect` does.

Comment: Is there any quick fix in the code for this? Maybe specify somewhere `64` rather than `32` or viceversa?

Comment: try build a 32bits binary : using rustup default stable-i686.

You still can, of course change ::std::mem::transmute(tenv) to ::std::mem::transmute(tenv as i64), but IDK if it's valid :D

Comment: Running `rustup default stable-i686` results in this `thread 'main' panicked at 'Unable to find libclang: "the \`libclang\` shared library could not be opened: /usr/local/opt/llvm/lib/libclang.dylib"'`

Comment: @octavian: The quickest fix would be to fork the crate (its code is likely on github), patch it with `isize` instead of `i32` and then use your local fork until your PR is merged into the official one.